# Wordpress theme get the current page and number of Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I searched on-line all over the place for this.  I really wish there had been a good answer.

## The Question

**What I wanted:**

 I wanted a way to get the current blog page index and max number of pages from a footer type file. (So I can make a navigation bar with page numbers)

**What should work:**

According to [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Inside_the_Loop_variables) while inside the loop there should be $page and $numpages global variables.

**It wasn't:**

These were not working for me in loop.php, loop-single.php or in the file I actually wanted access to it in (blog-footer.php in my theme).  Tested inside and outside of my has_posts while loop.

## The solution using the answer's code

**Note:**  I have the answer, I'm making this question to share it.  I think there may be a better answer or an explanation for why $page and $numpages weren't working so if you know that please post your answer!

**If you're interested I wrote some code to create a paged navigation bar**

This is what I wanted the current/max page for.  **This is the functioning version**

You'll likely want to style the ul elemetns

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php
        $DOTS = -1;
        $CURRENT = -2;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        $page = get_query_var('paged', 1);
        if ($page === 0)
            $page = 1;

        $links = [];

        if ($page !== 1) {
            ?>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link( __( '&laquo;') ); ?></li>
            <?php
        }

        if ($page > 3) {
            $links[] = 1;

            if ($page > 4)
                $links[] = $DOTS;
        }

        for ($i = $page-2; $i <= ($page + 2); $i++) {

            if ($i <= 0)
                continue;
            else if ($i > $pages)
                break;
            else if ($page === $i)
                $links[] = $CURRENT;
            else
                $links[] = $i;

        }

        if ($pages-2 > $page) {
            if ($pages-3 > $page)
                $links[] = $DOTS;

            $links[] = $pages;
        }

        foreach($links as $link) {

            if ($link === $DOTS)
                echo '<li><a>...</a></li>';
            else if ($link === $CURRENT)
                echo "<li><a class=\"currently-open highlight\">$page</a></li>";
            else

            echo "<li><a href=\"/blog/page/$link\">$link</a><li>";
        }

        if ($page != $pages) {
            ?>
                <li><?php next_posts_link( __( '&raquo;') ); ?></li>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I retrieved this information via the following functions:

```
$pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
$page = get_query_var('paged', 1);

if ($page === 0)
    $page = 1;
```

If you're on page one paged seems to return 0.

**Note:** I think there may be a better answer or an explanation for why $page and $numpages aren't working so if you know that please post your answer!